# concide top of one div to bottom of the other div both with height:auto; in css

Tags: css

I want to position a comments container relative to the post container . But the Post text can be of different size so i made it auto height . same for the comment container as it can contain any number of comments . but if i position the comment container as

```
#wallwrap .comment_container_out
        {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    bottom:-15px;
    left:80px;
           }
```

it concides the bottom of the comment container to the bottom of the post container so when the number of comments increase , the height of the comment container also increases but it expands to upward direction while i want it to expand in the downward direction.
The post container is

```
#wallwrap .text_post

    {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    font-size:10px; 
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,  sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:5px 10px;
    width:220px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of your problem is that you're using position:absolute, which will remove the element from the normal HTML "flow". When you then set it to "bottom: 0", it will always fix itself to the bottom of the container, but grow vertically upwards.

Why are you trying to position it absolutely? Position:absolute should always be a last resort. If you're just trying to separate the post area from the comments, I would simply add a margin-bottom to the post area.

Comment: because i want to position the comments container relative to the post container . and again , using the margin bottom option will again do the same problem . the comment container will grow vertically . i cannot use margin-top option as i don't know the size of the post .. it can always vary

Comment: I guess I'm really confused - you want the comment area to appear relative to the post *in what way*? Above it? Below it? To the left? Based on your CSS, it looks like you want the comments to appear below the post. If you had a visual of what you're trying to achieve, that would help a lot.

The normal pattern for posts and comments is that the comment form appears below the post. If the post precedes the comments in the markup, and normal HTML flow applies, this will be the case.